# Native American coming of age young adult novel published prior to 1981

Tags: identification-request

I’m trying to id a Native American coming of age short novel that I read in 3rd grade (published prior to 1981) similar to Call It Courage that features a young boy who wanders off into the wilderness for I think a coming of age ceremony . . . I remember that moccasins or learning how to make them was an important element, as well as either making or finding a stone knife . . .